# Sort XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, sorting, recursive-query

I have an xml that describes a catalog tree. It can have any number of child nodes. Here is an example:

```
<Catalog name="AccessoriesCatalog">
<Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory" name="1532" id="1532">
</Category>
<Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory" name="16115" id="16115">
    <ParentCategory>1532</ParentCategory>
</Category>
<Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory" name="16116" id="16116">
    <ParentCategory>16115</ParentCategory>
</Category>
<Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory" name="16126" id="16126">
    <ParentCategory>16115</ParentCategory>
</Category>
<Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory" name="16131" id="16131">
    <ParentCategory>1532</ParentCategory>
</Category>
<Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory" name="16132" id="16132">
    <ParentCategory>16131</ParentCategory>
</Category>
<Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory" name="16136" id="16136">
    <ParentCategory>16131</ParentCategory>
</Category>
<Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory" name="16139" id="16139">
    <ParentCategory>16131</ParentCategory>
</Category>
<Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory" name="16144" id="16144">
    <ParentCategory>16131</ParentCategory>
</Category>
<Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory" name="16195" id="16195">
    <ParentCategory>16131</ParentCategory>
</Category>
```

I need to be able to sort it on Category name and ParentCategory. All parent categories shall come first in the xml and the "leaf categories" shall come last. In this sample the xml is already sorted.

Above xml looks like this when it is represented as a tree
1532
-16115
--16116
--16126
-16131
--16132
--16136
--16139
--16144
--16195

I want it to be sorted like this
1532
-16115
-16131
--16116
--16126
--16132
--16136
--16139
--16144
--16195

It can be several levels of child elements (in this case only a 3 level tree). I want all level 1 elements to come first in the xml, then all level 2 elements and then all level 3 elements etc.

Comment: I'nm confused about the relationship between a `Category` and its `ParentCategory`. In your example it looks like the elements are sorted only by the category name.

Comment: You could achieve the output shown simply by sorting numerically on @name (or for that matter, @id). Could you show us an example to illustrate where ParentCategory comes into the picture?

Comment: If this is a flat representation of a tree, then `/Catalog/Category[@id = ../Category/ParentCategory]` will select every parent **in any level** and `/Catalog/Category[not(@id = ../Category/ParentCategory)]` will select every leaf. It's not clear if you want this kind of order (all parent, all leaf) or you want the descendant after each parent.

Comment: Excellent question, +1. See my answer for a complete solution.

Comment: Also, added extensive explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kElemById" match="Category"
  use="@id"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>

   <xsl:call-template name="sortHier">
    <xsl:with-param name="pNodes" select=
    "*[ParentCategory]"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="pParents" select=
    "*[not(ParentCategory)]"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="sortHier">
  <xsl:param name="pNodes"/>
  <xsl:param name="pParents"/>

  <xsl:apply-templates select=
   "$pParents|$pNodes[not($pParents)]">
   <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>

   <xsl:if test="$pNodes and $pParents">
    <xsl:variable name="vNewParents"
     select="key('kElemById', $pNodes/ParentCategory)
                [not(@id=$pParents/@id)]
     "/>

    <xsl:variable name="vNewChildren"
     select="$pNodes[not(@id=$vNewParents/@id)]"/>

    <xsl:call-template name="sortHier">
     <xsl:with-param name="pNodes"
          select="$vNewChildren"/>
     <xsl:with-param name="pParents"
          select="$vNewParents"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (based on the provided one, but shuffled/unsorted):

```
<Catalog name="AccessoriesCatalog">
    <Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory"
    name="16144" id="16144">
        <ParentCategory>16131</ParentCategory>
    </Category>
    <Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory"
    name="16116" id="16116">
        <ParentCategory>16115</ParentCategory>
    </Category>
    <Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory"
    name="16126" id="16126">
        <ParentCategory>16115</ParentCategory>
    </Category>
    <Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory"
    name="16131" id="16131">
        <ParentCategory>1532</ParentCategory>
    </Category>
    <Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory"
    name="16132" id="16132">
        <ParentCategory>16131</ParentCategory>
    </Category>
    <Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory"
    name="16136" id="16136">
        <ParentCategory>16131</ParentCategory>
    </Category>
    <Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory"
    name="16139" id="16139">
        <ParentCategory>16131</ParentCategory>
    </Category>
    <Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory"
    name="16115" id="16115">
        <ParentCategory>1532</ParentCategory>
    </Category>
    <Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory"
    name="1532" id="1532"></Category>
    <Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory"
    name="16195" id="16195">
        <ParentCategory>16131</ParentCategory>
    </Category>
</Catalog>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<Catalog name="AccessoriesCatalog">
   <Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory" name="1532" id="1532"/>
   <Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory" name="16115" id="16115">
      <ParentCategory>1532</ParentCategory>
   </Category>
   <Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory" name="16131" id="16131">
      <ParentCategory>1532</ParentCategory>
   </Category>
   <Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory" name="16116" id="16116">
      <ParentCategory>16115</ParentCategory>
   </Category>
   <Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory" name="16126" id="16126">
      <ParentCategory>16115</ParentCategory>
   </Category>
   <Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory" name="16132" id="16132">
      <ParentCategory>16131</ParentCategory>
   </Category>
   <Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory" name="16136" id="16136">
      <ParentCategory>16131</ParentCategory>
   </Category>
   <Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory" name="16139" id="16139">
      <ParentCategory>16131</ParentCategory>
   </Category>
   <Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory" name="16144" id="16144">
      <ParentCategory>16131</ParentCategory>
   </Category>
   <Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory" name="16195" id="16195">
      <ParentCategory>16131</ParentCategory>
   </Category>
</Catalog>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **Recursively called named template** with two parameters: the "set of current parents" (or "last found parents") and the set of the current (still not processed) nodes.
2. **Stop condition**: Either the "set of current parents" or the "set of current nodes" or both are empty. Here we output (and sort by `@name`) the remaining non-empty parameter-set.
3. **Recursive step**: The immediate children of the "current parents" become the new "current parents". The rest of the "current nodes" become the new "current nodes. Copy all the current-parents or all the current-nodes if there are no current-parents left.

**Update**:

In comments the OP has been claiming that the solution was working on small files,

> "But when I try it on the whole xml
>   with more elements and more levels it
>   is not working. The xml I have is
>   about 8Mb so I can't post it here."

I asked him to provide (offline) the XML files and when I got them, I have confirmed that this solution performs without problem on both the small and the bigger (44000 lines, 700KB) files that I was provided with.

**The performance on the bigger file wasn't too bad** with the exception of MSXML3.

**Here is the performance data for the 44000 lines file**, as seen on my 8 years old (2GB RAM, 3GHz single core) PC:

```
MSXML3:                 91 sec.

MSXML6:                  6 sec.

AltovaXML (XMLSpy):      6 sec.

Saxon 6.5.4:             2 sec.

Saxon 9.1.05:            1.6 sec.

XslCompiledTransform     1.3 sec.

XQSharp:                 0.8 sec.
```

Comment: Hi, this solution works almost as I wnat it, thanks. But when I try it on the whole xml with more elements and more levels it is not working. The xml I have is about 8Mb so I can't post it here. Or is it possible to upload it somewhere?

Comment: @Thomas: You have to be more specific about the meaning of "not working". And there are planty of places you can make the XML available at -- one is http://www.skydrive.com. You can also send this file to me. I am using the google-based mail and my id is dnovatchev.

Comment: @Thomas: I tested this solution on documents with more levels and it produces the wanted results. I guess that your XML document has some data anomaly (such as containing a loop), that makes it not a tree but a more general kind of graph. Please, consider accepting this answer and posting a new question with your new data structure defined and provided.

Comment: @Dimitre, the xml is standard Microsoft Commerce Server format and it describes a catalog tree. You can find an example here http://www.volvopentashop.com/MarincenterSyd/en-GB/Details/AccessoriesCatalog. I will send you the xml. After you have tried your xslt on that, take a look at the element with name 12100. This element has a parent specified with name 1797. But the actual parent element is listed later in the trasformed output. It should be listed before the element with id 12100. Parents should be listed first in the output. First, parent elements at level 1, then parents at lev 2 etc.

Comment: One more thing. I want to have the parents listed first since this xml file will be imported Commerce Server (CS) and CS reads it element by element. If CS reads an element that has a parent specified and that parent has not yet been imported then an error will occure. That's why i want to have all parents first and in order by their level in the tree.

Comment: @Thomas: The algorithm that this transformation uses generates any parent before its children.

Comment: @Thomas: I have updated my answer with the results of running the solution on the real file that you sent (thanks for that). Will you, please, be so kind as to finally accept this answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer could be found here: http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/FAQ-XML-Sort-XML-By-Multiple-Attributes-XSLT